# Bold text not showing in hero cards

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm having some problems with bold text in hero cards, currently I build my hero card like so:

```
var workloadCard = new HeroCard
        {
            Title = $"Partido #{number+1}",
            Subtitle = $"**{matches[number].equipo1} vs {matches[number].equipo2}**",
            Text = ($"El {fecha.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)} a las:  \nMéxico: **{matches[number].hora.Replace(" ", "")}**  \nRusia: **{horaRUs}**  \nEn {matches[number].sede}"),
            Images = new System.Collections.Generic.List<CardImage> { new CardImage($"{url}") },
            Buttons = cardButtons,
        };
```

The problem is that the text between ** ** is shown with asterisks instead of being bold:

```
$"**{matches[number].equipo1} vs {matches[number].equipo2}**
```

Turns into

```
**México vs Suecia**
```

Instead of

**México vs Suecia**

This happens in any part of the hero card but otherwise works in flat responses, what is the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Which channel are you using?

Comment: I'm using directline

Answer (score 1):

Hero cards accept html tags inside them so I fixed this problem by doing this:

```
$"<b>{matches[number].equipo1} vs {matches[number].equipo2}</b>
```

Instead of this:

```
$"**{matches[number].equipo1} vs {matches[number].equipo2}**
```

Comment: It's not Hero Card that is accepting html tags, it's the channel that you are using which is handling those tags. If you use Hero Cards in other channels you may bot your html tags visible

Comment: How does that work? When I try to add tags in a simple message it just displays raw text I only got them to work in herocards

Comment: in an activity, you would have to do this: `activity.TextFormat = TextFormatTypes.Markdown;`  as Nicolas implicated, this html will not work in all channels.

Comment: According to [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Csimple-html#formatting-cards-with-html):  "HTML tags are supported for simple cards such as the hero and thumbnail card. Markdown is not supported." so this seems to be the correct answer